# Button click using iMacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to automate the click of a button and then save the file to a local folder. But the download event is getting fired on some other button. How can I specify the button I want to be clicked in my macro.

My URL: https://apkpure.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antiaircraft.firegms
My iMacro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://apkpure.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antiaircraft.firegms
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=11 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>APK
```

On running above macro, it downloads "Ultimate Moto Racer" instead of "Anti Aircraft Fire"

Answer (score 0):

Chance POS value in this command.

```
TAG POS=11 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>APK
```